# Baggage transfer international flight with missed connection and airline changed

Tags: air-travel

I am travelling from US to India via Air France - CMH--->DTW--->CDG--->IGI. but due to some technical difficulties in plane I missed the connecting flight. Now AirFrance has given me another ticket of AI flight late in night to IGI. I need to know how my baggage would be transferred as the AI terminal is far from the AirFrance terminal i had to take a train and bus to reach the AI terminal in CDG.

Comment: Did you ask the airline? They're probably the only ones who can answer this question. Anything we offer will be either speculation, or based on passed experience, neither of which is likely to mean much in your specific situation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the specific circumstances of one specific journey, and likey cannot be generalized.  "Too localized."

Comment: @Flmizy I don't think it's that "localized". Re-accommodations onto alternative carriers happen from time to time, and those people who check luggage may wish to know how to check whether their bags are being interlined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you checked in for your first flight you were given a baggage receipt. It is a small sticker and it is often stuck to the back of a paper boarding card or (irritatingly) your passport.

The receipt looks something like this:
[image: KLM luggage receipt]
but yours won't be green.

At least an hour before your flight, find an Air India staff member (at the check in desk or at the gate, before boarding has begun), present the baggage receipt and the boarding pass and ask the agent to confirm your baggage is on the cargo manifest to be loaded onto the aircraft.

At this time there is still time to find your bag if Air France forgot to tell Air India about your baggage.

The actual practicalities of how baggage is moved around the airport is not really very interesting. Newer airports have extensive underground baggage train systems controlled by computers. But in most airports a guy will just pick up your bag with the other interterminal transfer baggage and drive it on a truck to the other terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your update, yes I have the updated receipt. I called up Airfrance and Air India both - got some hints from Airfrance to check at the Gate with AI people.Hope that works..

Comment: Atlast everything went ok, I was also given an upgrade which is like a boon. The bags were automatically transferred. AI confirmed it when I went an ask them. Thanks once again for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Baggage transfers are handled using trailers hauled by small motorized tractors.  These vehicles can easily travel between terminals.  There could be a baggage conveyor system connecting the terminals, but if there is not, your bags will be taken in this or another sort of vehicle.

In case your baggage does not get to the flight you are on, it will be sent on a later flight and, generally, delivered to you.